# ASP.NET runtime error: Length can not be less than zero. Parameter name: length

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using visual studio 2008 on vista business. We just recently upgraded from xp. Now when I open a web project  I get this error

> ASP.NET runtime error: Length can not be less than zero. Parameter name: length<

in every .aspx file on this line of code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactNotes.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContactNotes" Title="Contact Note" %>
```

This started happening after new install, anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?  It will avoid a lot of guessing. :)

Comment: have you checked your iis settings. I am not sure but please see.

Comment: I verified the iis settins. I am still having this issue.

Tried uninstalling VS and reinstalling - still fails.

Reinstalled Vista, now installing VS. I will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a Web.config issue. I remember getting this error when in the ASP.NET membership provider section, we had a constraint on the minimum password length, or something like that. This resulted in that error. Look for something similar. I know this is rather vague, but perhaps it'll steer you in the right direction.